# How to share the composition across components in api-composition style?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

In my application I have two separate components:

- products component (show the products in the ui)
- filter-products component (show the criteria in ui)
- total-filter-products component (show the total criteria items was applied in ui, for example my current search is `age`,`name` so on)

They are separate **and not** communicate with input (`:`) or output (`@`).

I also have a `ts` file, with function `useProducts` as "api-composition style".

```
export const useProducts = () => {

  const criteria = ref({ category: null, age: null, color: null });
  
  const items = computed(() => { return store.get('products').filter(p => filterByCritiria(p)) });

  const load = () => {

    const params = parseSome(criteria.value);

    axios.post('/api/...', { params }).then(r => { store.set('products', r.data)});
  }

  return { criteria, items, load }

}
```

In the `products` component, I just get the `products` from `useProducts` and bind to the template:

```
 setup() {
  const { products } = useProducts();
  return { products } 
 }
```

In the filter-products, I get the `criteria` from `useProducts` and bind to the template. every time some value change in `criteria` ref (using v-model), I run the `load` function.

```
   setup() {
      const { criteria, load } = useProducts();
      watch(() => criteria.value, (v) => load() });

      return { criteria } 
     }
```

In total-filter-products component I do some logic to display the criteria:

```
     setup() {
      const { criteria } = useProducts();

      return { criteria: parse(criteria) } 
     }
```

The problem with this is every time I call to `useProducts` I execute the function and get new variables.

I get three times the `criteria`. so if I change the `criteria` in `filter-products`, the `total-filter-products` and `products` components will never know about it.

How to share the composition across components in api-composition style?